# Model validation errors in the Ext JS 5.0 framework

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

How can you get validation errors of a model, specifically in **Ext JS 5.0**?  As in version 4.2 we did this:

```js
var rec = Ext.create("ModelName", {...});
var errors = rec.validate();
if (!errors.isValid()) {
    form.markInvalid(errors);
}
```

However [`validate()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-validate) is now marked as deprecated in the documentation and calling it no longer returns any error messages.  I've looked at the `getValidation()` method which is introduced in 5.0 but it doesn't return any error messages which can be passed to a form component and there are no clear examples of how else to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always had my configuration the other way around with the validators in the form itself - that way [`Ext.form.Panel` `isValid`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-isValid) automatically marks the relevant fields as needed.  It is fairly straight-forward to do what you want however with a few modifications - **be forewarned** though that `getValidation` returns a private utility class potentially making code susceptible to changes in future versions of the framework.

To start with, `Ext.data.Model` `getValidation` returns an instance of `Ext.data.Validation` which is notably a simple data-model itself.  It is basically a key-value map of each field with corresponding validity - If a value is **strictly** boolean `true` then the field is valid, anything else ***i.e.*** a `string` (error message) then the field is invalid.  For convenience, you could write a function that will return the errors in the format you need - in this example I've overridden the validation model itself but ideally you would incorporate the logic into your own models via extension or perhaps a [mixin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Mixin):

```js
Ext.define('override.data.Validation', {
    override: 'Ext.data.Validation',
    getErrors: function(){
        var errors = [];
        Ext.iterate(this.getData(), function(field, value){
            if(true !== value) this.push({ id: field, msg: value });        
        }, errors);
        return errors;
    }    
});
```

Then modify your logic above as follows:

```js
var rec = Ext.create("ModelName", { /***/ });
if(!rec.isValid()){
    form.markInvalid( rec.getValidation().getErrors() );
}
```

[**» demo / fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7lg)

---

It's also worth noting that if you are validating a model in this way the [`Presence`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.validator.Presence) validator always seems to return `true` (valid) regardless of whether or not you set a value - presumably because a `defaultValue` will exist on the record objects prototype?  So I incorporated a custom validator into the demonstration:

```js
Ext.define('validator.NotEmpty', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.validator.Validator',
    alias: 'data.validator.notempty',
    validate: function(value){
        return !Ext.isEmpty(value) || 'Field must not be empty';
    }
});
```